# Github use ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I know Github.com uses Rails.

But what template language does Github use? And what css framework does Github use?

Comment: Please try to correct the grammar of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

The original question was somewhat confusing and seemed to conflate Github with Rails. My answer below aimed to clarify the difference. The changes/clarifications made to the question later (after I posted my answer) have lead to the answer below to no longer respond to the question as (now) posted, but I cannot delete the answer as it has been marked as accepted...

==================================

It's hard to tell from the wording, but I think you're confused about several languages/tools that are found in Rails. Maybe this will help:

- Git (http://gitscm.org/)is a version control tool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) used frequently in Rails projects. It's used to manage the source code in your projects (versions, branches with different functions, etc.)
- Github (https://github.com) is a place you can store source code that is managed with Git
- the default language used in Rails views is called ERB (introduction example here: http://thinkvitamin.com/code/rails-views-erb-part-1/)
- rails 3.1 uses Sass to create CSS files by default (http://sass-lang.com/)

Those are the languages you've mentioned having trouble with, and they're a portion of the languages you'll need to familiarize yourself with if you want to use Rails to its full extent.

You can learn more about Rails online (for example: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, http://railscasts.com/), or with books (http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails and http://www.manning.com/katz/ are 2 good books. The first one is easier for beginners, the second one goes into more detail and is for more advanced readers).

Comment: I think the op was asking whether Github is using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Github uses Ruby on Rails.

When asked about the technology stack that they use to Sam Lambert, Director of technology he said:

> MySQL is our core data store that we used for storing all data that powers the site as well as the metadata around the users. We also use Redis a little bit for some non-persistent caching, and things like memcached.
>
> C, Shell, Ruby — quite a simple, monolithic stack. We’re really not an overcomplex shop, we don’t intend to try and drop new languages for every small project.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/collections/projects-that-power-github) to see the projects that power Github.

Answer (score 0):

It appears github has moved towards converting their monolith from rails into microservices made in other languages.  Doubtful rails is completely out of the picture IMHO.

https://www.theregister.com/2018/08/16/github_rails_microsoft/